# Why are html elements with (@media print display: none; ) showing as white-space when printing and how do I remove the white-space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, removing-whitespace

My problem is unwanted white-space when printing.

I have seen lots of posts asking how to hide or show elements when printing, but I have not seen any regarding this white-space problem.

I have two div elements both contain buttons. I have targeted the divs and the buttons with an external style sheet using css attribute  display: none;.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css"type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

When I right click the web page and choose print, the print preview does not display the buttons as expected. However the space occupied by the divs and buttons appears at white-space in the print preview and is printed as white-space if I actually print the web page.

I have checked theses elements for top & bottom margin properties and they are computed with no top or bottom margin in chrome browser inspector. Same goes for the elements immediately before and after the targeted divs. I have tried targeting the divs and buttons with css margin: 0; still same result.
There are also`<br>` break tags involved here. I have targeted those as well with display: none;
That seems to have removed a small amount of the white-space.
I can provide screen shots if required. I can also provide dimensions of white space and elements if required.
Is there anyway to eliminate this white-space @ media print using a css solution, or do I have to trigger a javascript function to change innerHTML eliminating the divs completely when printing?

html:

```
<div class="row" id="sign_up_c">
    <p class="lead  text-center">Please sign me up for the 6 day Carnival Cruise.
        <br>
        Please fill out and print this sign-up form for<u>each</u>person.
    </p>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="row text-center noPrint">
    <button type="button" onclick="fillTableFunction(); return false, printContent('table_sign_up_c')" class="btn btn-primary"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Print form</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row text-center noPrint">
    <script>$(function () {  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()})</script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Your security & privacy are important to us." 
        data-content="We have made efforts to ensure your personal information is secure. We only share your information where it is required by law. If you are viewing this on a public computer please be sure to close the browser after completing & printing the form.">
        Security & Privacy
    </button>
</div>
```

css:

```
@media print{

    body, html {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    }

    .print-only { 
        visibility: visible;
    }

    button.btn.btn-primary {
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    button.btn.btn-lg.btn-danger {
        display: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .btn-danger { 
        display:none;
    }

    br{
        display: none;
    }

    .noPrint {
        display: none !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }

    #itinerary { 
    transform: scale(.6);
    }
    .myform { 
    transform: scale(.6);
    }
}


@media screen {
    .print-only {visibility: hidden;}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `script` tag is causing problems?  That's not a usual place to find a `script` tag.  Also, have you tried giving your div height and width of zero?

Comment: @jmargolivst. I added height and width zero to css. Moved script tag to head.Same result.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the white-space occurs in chrome, firefox and edge.

Comment: Any solution? Please share if so

Comment: @Dragolis I found the best solution for my case was to use jQuery to remove the unwanted html elements prior to printing. Check out this pen. [CodePen] https://codepen.io/learn4earn/pen/YzXOeyW [CodePen]